# Welcher Fall nach zwei Präpositionen (mit und ohne)

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

Im Satz  «Das Resultat wird mit und ohne dem/den Gebrauch eines Assistenzsystems berechnet.»
würde ich logischerweise den Akkusativ wählen, d.h. den Fall, den die Präposition *ohne* verlangt. Allerdings würde mein Ohr den Dativ vorziehen.
Ich muss dazu sagen, dass ich seit mehr als 40 Jahren nicht mehr im deutschen Sprachraum lebe.

Comment: Die bei weitem einfachste Methode, sich hier aus der Affäre zu ziehen, ist, den Artikel einfach wegzulassen und es dem Leser zu überlassen, welchen Fall "Gebrauch" hier denn wohl haben könnte. Funktioniert in deinem Beispiel ziemlich gut (beantwortet deine Frage aber leider nicht).

Comment: Wie kann überhaupt etwas mit etwas Zweitem **und** ohne dieses Zweite berechnet werden? Entweder es wird mit diesem oder ohne dieses berechnet - Betonung auf oder. Oder finden zwei Berechnungen statt?

Comment: Zu den beiden sehr guten Antworten von bakunin und David Vogt möchte ich ergänzen, dass du in deinem Beispiel nicht nur zwei Präpositionen reihst, die zufälligerweise unterschiedliche Kasus verlangen, sondern zwei sich gegenseitig ausschließende Bedeutungen zusammen zwingst. In einem solchen Fall fühlt sich die Fügung mit *und* für mich semantisch falsch an und ich würde eher *sowohl ... als auch* verwenden: "Das Resultat wird sowohl mit als auch ohne (den) Gebrauch eines Assistenzsystems berechnet."

Answer (score 2):

In diesem Satz kann man keinen Kasus wählen, weil der Dativ nur zu "mit" und der Akkusativ nur zu "ohne" passt. Das lässt sich nur vermeiden, indem du den Artikel weglässt, weil dann das Substantiv den Kasus nicht erkennen lässt und also dein Ohr nicht mehr irritiert wird.

Comment: Wie die Sprachpraxis zeigt, kann man sehr wohl.

Answer (score 2):

In einem solchen Fall sollte man eben nicht das [Zeugma](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_(Sprache)) (so heißt diese Zusammenziehung) verwenden, die nur dann funktioniert, wenn man *Gleiches* zusammenspannt. Man kann diese Figur *ironisierend* verwenden, wie etwa Heinz Erhardt:

> Ich heiße nicht nur Heinz Erhardt, sondern Sie auch herzlich willkommen.

In einem solchen Fall ist durch die satirische Verwendung einiges gedeckt, was man ansonsten nicht darf. Karl Kraus über ein von ihm verwendetes Zitat:

> Gegen Ehrenstein? Nein, von!

Man kann das Zeugma auch ernsthaft verwenden:

> Der See kann sich, der Landvogt nicht erbarmen.
> <sub>F. Schiller, *Wilhelm Tell*</sub>

Aber wenn man in dieses Joch (das ist die Übersetzung von "Zeugma") so unterschiedliche Zugtiere wie Dativ und Akkusativ spannt, dann landet man bei der von Dir angeführten Konstruktion, die schon Schiller als Stilfehler angekreidet wurde:

> Was heißt und zu welchem Ende studiert man Universalgeschichte

Das war der Titel der Antrittsvorlesung Schillers in Jena am 26. Mai 1789. "Universalgeschichte" stellt hier aber einmal den Nominativ (Was heißt - wer?) und das andere mal den Akkusativ (Wozu studiert man - wen?) vor. Genau das geht aber nicht - selbst dann nicht, wenn man die unterschiedlichen Kasus nicht an den Endungen erkennt.  Eine erschöpfende Diskussion dieses Themas (nebst weiteren Beispielen) findet sich bei Karl Kraus' "Die Sprache" unter "[Ein klassisches Zeugma](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/kraus/sprache/chap014.html)"

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man in den [DWDS Korpora](https://www.dwds.de/r) sucht, findet man für *mit und ohne* nur Beispiele, bei denen der Akkusativ folgt.

> Sie testen unterschiedliche Versionen, mit und ohne **die** neuen Erkenntnisse, und wo sich Verbesserungen ergeben, siegt das Neue. (*Zeit*, 12.2.2015)

> Zur nächsten Sitzung am Freitag kommender Woche will Riester Berechnungen über die Entwicklung der Renten, Rentenhöhen und Beitragssätze mit und ohne **den** umstrittenen demographischen Faktor bis zum Jahr 2030 vorlegen. (*Tagesspiegel*, 20.1.2000)

Den Dativ findet man dagegen nicht. Die Duden-Grammatik (9. Auflage) scheint die sprachliche Praxis also korrekt zu beschreiben, wenn es bei Randnummer 923 heißt:

> Manchmal werden zwei Präpositionen unterschiedlicher Kasusrektion koordiniert. In diesem Fall bestimmt die letzte Präposition den Kasus: […]

Man hält sich auch selbst an diese Regel, wie folgende Kapitelüberschrift zeigt.

> 2.11.1.2 Gebundener Gebrauch mit und ohne indefinit**en** Artikel